# Implement a Google play time validity of an app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-lvl

I want to upload an app on google play. I want to implement time validity of app subscription is one year.

Once user pay for one year then user can use that app for an year. After one year automatically the app stop working and user need to buy it again from google play.

How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at Google Play Billing API.

Since version 3 they support subscription billing which is what you are looking for.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

Comment: I need to set on google play developer console for this only right?. Is it something i need to do in my code to achieve this.